# Are very massive neutron stars highly streching wavelenghts of their emitted light?

Tags: gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, neutron-stars

Can be possible that more massive or more denser neutron stars stretch the wavelengths of their emitted EM-waves more than less massive and less denser neutron stars?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about gravitational redshift which can be approximated using the equation

$$\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_0} \approx \frac{GM}{r c^2}$$

where $\lambda$ is the shifted wavelength, $\lambda_0$ is the rest wavelength and $r$ is the distance from the centre of a neutron star of  mass $M$.

We can see from this equation that as $M$ increases the amount of redshift increases and since the density of a star increases as its mass increases, this will have the same effect.